# Why coproduct in the algebra of linear operators is actually a coproduct?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, universal-algebra, coalgebras

Coproduct in a coalgebra $V$, where $V$ is also a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$, is defined as a $\mathbb{K}-$linear map $\Delta : V \rightarrow V\otimes V$ satisfying two diagrams obtained from the diagrams describing associativity and existence of unit in associative unital algebras by inverting the arrows. In particular, the coassociativity diagram is satisfied:
[Coassociativity of coproduct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TxkB.png)

which means
$$(\Delta \otimes I) \circ \Delta = (I \otimes \Delta) \circ \Delta$$

It is suggested (for example, on the [corresponding Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalgebra)) that the coproduct in the algebra of linear operators is
$$\Delta : A \rightarrow A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes A$$
where $\otimes$ is the "exterior tensor product" (what is its exact definition is unclear to me, but it appears to have properties similar to the regular tensor product). I assume $1$ here is just the unit operator $I$, because otherwise the map wouldn't be from $V$ to $V\otimes V$.
Let us check the coassociativity: take a random operator $A$.
$$\Delta A = A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes A$$
$$\Delta \otimes I (A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes A)=$$
$$(A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes A)\otimes 1 + (1 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes 1)\otimes A=$$
$$A \otimes 1 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes A \otimes 1 + 2(1 \otimes 1 \otimes A)$$
Now let us calculate $(I \otimes \Delta) \circ \Delta$:
$$(I \otimes \Delta)(A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes A)=$$
$$= 2(A \otimes 1 \otimes 1)+ 1 \otimes A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes 1 \otimes A$$

Clearly, $(\Delta \otimes I) \circ \Delta \ne (I \otimes \Delta) \circ \Delta$. So why is this a coproduct? What am I missing?

*Edit:* the Wikipedia article appears to refer to the [fact](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schweigert/skripten/hskript.pdf) (p.20) that the universal enveloping algebra over a Lie group $\mathfrak{g}$ has a coproduct defined as $\Delta: x \rightarrow 1 \otimes x + x \otimes 1$, where $1$ is the actual $1$ as a number, living in the 0-th degree of the universal enveloping algebra. The angular momentum operator used as example in the article is an element of $\mathfrak{so}_{3}$, so it makes sense. However, I still do not understand why coassociativity condition is satisfied. The universal enveloping algebra is the factor of the tensor algebra $T(\mathfrak{g})$ by the ideal generated by elements of the form $x \otimes y - y \otimes x - [x, y]$. How do I use that to prove the two expressions to be equivalent? If $[x, y]$ was defined for any pair of elements of $U(\mathfrak{g})$, I could change the order of elements in monomials of the form $A \otimes 1 \otimes 1$ as follows:
$$A \otimes 1 \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes A \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes A \otimes 1 + A \otimes 1 \otimes 1$$
then, using the fact that $A \otimes 1 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes A \otimes 1= (A \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes A)\otimes 1$ and $A \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes A - [A, 1] = 0$, I would rewrite
$$A \otimes 1 \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes A \otimes 1 + [A, 1] \otimes 1$$
However, $[A, 1]$ is not defined (or so I think).

Comment: Please specify where on the Wikipedia page this precise claim is made. (Spoiler: nowhere.)

Comment: It is, of course, correct, that this precise claim is not present on the Wikipedia page, because the whole section in question is informal, and one has to deduce the precise claims oneself; that's why the section is called _Informal discussion_. If you can indicate the part I got wrong, please, do not hesitate to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my original question in the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357667/universal-enveloping-algebra-as-bialgebra). First, as was correctly indicated in the comments, I was originally mistaken about the algebra on which this coproduct is defined, and did not understand the definition itself. The coproduct $\Delta: x \rightarrow 1 \otimes x + x \otimes 1$ is defined on the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, which is the factor of the tensor algebra $\mathbb{K}\oplus \bigoplus_{i \ge 1}\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes i}$ by the ideal generated by elements of the form $x \otimes y - y \otimes x - [x, y]$, where $x, y \in \mathfrak{g}$, $[,]$ is the bracket in the Lie algebra. It has such a form specifically for elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ embedded into $U(\mathfrak{g})$. For the element $1 \in \mathbb{K}$, the coproduct is defined as $\Delta: 1\rightarrow 1 \otimes 1$, and not as $\Delta: 2(1 \otimes 1)$. It is done in this way, because coproduct in a Hopf algebra must be a morphism of algebras, hence, it must map the unit of $\mathbb{K}$ to the unit of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ (also because unit and counit must compose in identity). Then it is easy to check explicitly that coproduct is coassociative.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the Wikipedia page. It states that, for a *certain* coalgebra $C$ and a *certain* element $j$ of $C$ we have $\Delta(j) = j \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes j$. Your deduction that this equation defines a coalgebra structure for every vector space* and any element $1$ of it and all elements $j$ is not correct. Your proof confirms this.

For a more concrete example, consider the divided power bialgebra (in one variable), which is $K[X]$ with $\Delta(X) = X \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes X$ and $\varepsilon(X)=0$. Here, we have $\Delta(X^2)=X^2 \otimes 1 + 2 \cdot X \otimes X + 1 \otimes X^2$, and thus $\Delta(X^2) \neq X^2 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes X^2$.

*Even though you have said this only  for $\mathrm{End}(V)$, it is clear that you never use the algebra structure on this algebra, you only use the vector space structure and some random element $1$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you suggest where to look for a sensible description of the actual coproduct of which the Wikipedia article talks?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help with physics. Ask a separate question maybe.

Comment: In physics this is just how the total angular momentum operator is described. I've never seen a connection to coproducts being brought up in physics textbooks, so, perhaps, there is some well-known coproduct on the tensor algebra, or on the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{so}_{3}$, of which this is a special case?

Comment: It appears to be the coproduct defined on the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_{3}$, or, perhaps, $\mathfrak{sl}_{3}$, and the coproduct in any $U(\mathfrak{g})$ algebra is defined (see p.20: https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schweigert/skripten/hskript.pdf) as $x \rightarrow 1 \otimes x + x \otimes 1$. So the original question remains: how does this give coassociativity? How can one use the fact that elements of the form $x \otimes y - y \otimes x - [x, y]$ are equivalent to zero to prove the diagram?

Comment: Please read more carefully. $\Delta(x) = 1 \otimes x + x \otimes 1$ holds for $x \in \mathfrak{g}$, not for all elements of the algebra. Coass. follows formally from the one of $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{g}$, using the universal property. This is explained in the script. If it doesn't explain it well enough, just google "coalgebra structure on universal enveloping algebra" or something similar (it is even a Hopf algebra), there are tons of resources which explain that.

Comment: PS: MSE is not a discussion forum. You should not ask more and more questions and change the original question. This is bad practice. I have answered your original question already. If you have another one: open another one.